# WCF xml response

Tags: wcf

I need my wcf service will respond the message in the following format.

```
<Date>  
1;test;306;values;1,2;product  
</Date>
```

How i have to create my WCF service.

Give some sample code.

Comment: Are you sure about the single quotes?

Comment: @marc_s I need SOAP service, my end client only accept this type of message format.

Comment: A SOAP service will have **at least** some `<soap:envelope>` and `<soap:body>` tags around this - you cannot have **just this** XML as a return from a SOAP service....

Comment: @marc_s Is rest service will do it.

Comment: You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2008/08/09/more-on-restful-service-with-wcf-and-pox-poco.aspx) which illustrates how you could build a REST WCF service exposing a POCO as POX.

Answer (score 0):

With this setup, you're getting pretty close (and probably as close as you can get):

**Service contract:**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Response GetData(Request input);
}
```

**Message contracts** for request and response

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class Request
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "DateRequest")]
    public string Input { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class Response
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "Date")]
    public string ReturnString { get; set; }
}
```

When you implement a service based on this, and you call it with the proper values, you should get back a XML response like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <Date>1;test;306;values;1,2;product</Date>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: thanks marc got closer result but still the envelop, header and body tags are coming. thanks.

Comment: @santhosh: you won't be able to get rid of those if you have to have a SOAP service....